# How to get page.keyboard.press("[any key]") to dispatch a keypress event with page.keyboard.down("Control")

Tags: puppeteer

#### Steps to reproduce

**Tell us about your environment:**

- Puppeteer version: v1.19.0
- Platform / OS version: Windows 8.1
- URLs (if applicable):
- Node.js version: 10.16.0

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

I have the files:

```
PuppeteerTest/
├── test/main.spec.js
index.html
```

index.html

```html
<textarea></textarea>

<script>
    const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
    textarea.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = `KeyCode: ${e.keyCode}, Ctrl Pressed: ${e.ctrlKey}, Shift Pressed: ${e.shiftKey}`
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    });
</script>
```

test/main.spec.js

```js
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

describe("Control Key Issue", async () => {
    it("Doesn't register control-modified keypresses", async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 50});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(__dirname + `/../index.html`);
        const textarea = await page.$("textarea");
        await textarea.focus();
        await page.keyboard.down("Control"); // I've also tried ControlLeft;
        await page.keyboard.press("Enter"); // I've also tried "A" and "B"

        const resultingP = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const p = document.querySelector("p");
            if (p) {
                return p.textContent;
            } else {
                return "No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated"
            }
        });
        expect(resultingP).to.not.equal("KeyCode: 10, Ctrl Pressed: true, Shift Pressed: false");
        expect(resultingP).to.equal("No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated");
        browser.close();
    }).timeout(30000);

// To prove Puppeteer works in other cases, I've made the following tests.

    it("Registers non-control-modified keypresses", async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 50});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(__dirname + `/../index.html`);
        const textarea = await page.$("textarea");
        await textarea.focus();
        await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

        const resultingP = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const p = document.querySelector("p");
            if (p) {
                return p.textContent;
            } else {
                return "No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated"
            }
        });
        expect(resultingP).to.equal("KeyCode: 13, Ctrl Pressed: false, Shift Pressed: false");
        expect(resultingP).to.not.equal("No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated");
        browser.close();
    }).timeout(30000);

    it("Registers shift-modified keypresses", async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 50});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(__dirname + `/../index.html`);
        const textarea = await page.$("textarea");
        await textarea.focus();
        await page.keyboard.down("Shift"); 
        await page.keyboard.press("Enter"); 

        const resultingP = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const p = document.querySelector("p");
            if (p) {
                return p.textContent;
            } else {
                return "No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated"
            }
        });
        expect(resultingP).to.equal("KeyCode: 13, Ctrl Pressed: false, Shift Pressed: true");
        expect(resultingP).to.not.equal("No keypress event was emitted, so no <p></p>s were generated");
        browser.close();
    }).timeout(30000);
});
```

**What is the expected result?**
Control + Enter creates a keypress event when done manually, so I expected it to dispatch a keypress event with `e.keyCode === 10` (or 13, but in the real world, Ctrl + Enter results in a keycode of 10). I expected `e.ctrlKey === true`.

**What happens instead?**
Nothing. No event occurs when Control is down and another key is pressed. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

This looks like a bug in puppeteer. But keep in mind, the `keypress` event does not listen on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keypress. Quote from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event):

> The **`keypress`** event is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys. Examples of keys that don't produce a character value are modifier keys such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Meta</kbd>.

But it should fire at least when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Solution**

What worked for me, was to listen for the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event instead in your HTML document. The change would be this line:

```js
textarea.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    // ...
});
```

---

Just gave it a try by using the first test ("Doesn't register control-modified keypresses") from your code. I modified the `expect(...)` line to `console.log(resultingP)` to print the result and it returned the following in the console:

```
KeyCode: 17, Ctrl Pressed: true, Shift Pressed: false
```

The page itself showed the following two lines:

```
KeyCode: 17, Ctrl Pressed: true, Shift Pressed: false
KeyCode: 13, Ctrl Pressed: true, Shift Pressed: false
```

Comment: In the real world, the `keypress` event is still fired when the key _after_ control is fired. It also modifies the keyCode to be 10 instead of 13, when combined with Enter. Also, your example shows "Shift Pressed: true". The issue is getting KeyCode 13 (or 10) in Puppeteer when Ctrl is pressed in Puppeteer. One of the lead Puppeteer developers, Joel Einbinder, assigned himself to my issue on GitHub, so I think this is a bug.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally copied the wrong results, updated my answer. You are right, this looks like a bug to me. It should trigger the event once for `keypress` also.